# Identity of strange bird with fish net tangled around one foot

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

[image: Heron on wall next to water]
This bird was photographed at a small beach in Rio de Janeiro, Brazil.

What kind of (ocean?) bird is this??

Comment: Where was this photo taken? Also, great pic!

Comment: When asking for a specific species, you should give more contextual details like the country / region it was taken and the season (the question is not always related to the same time you took the pic).

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! In the future, please [edit] your posts to include all the relevant information in a visible format! Thanks! 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be an immature black-crowned night heron, [*Nycticorax nycticorax*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-crowned_night_heron).

Lines of evidence:

- pale yellowish bill
- thick neck
- hunched back
- orange eyes
- head feather patterning consistent with "black crown" in adults

See these photos and captions published by the [Cornell Lab of Ornithology](https://www.allaboutbirds.org/guide/Black-crowned_Night-Heron/id):

> [image: juvenile black-crowned night heron]
> **Juvenile Black-crowned Night Heron**
> Thick-necked heron with a thick bill. Juveniles are brown and streaky overall. Note pale yellowish bill.
> © Evan Lipton
>
> [image: immature black-crowned night heron]
> **Immature Black-crowned Night Heron**
> Immature birds have a mix of juvenile and adult plumage. This individual has faint streaking on the chest, a dark gray cap, and a nearly complete dark gray back.
> © Alex Lamoreaux
>
> [image: adult black-crowned night heron]
> **Adult Black-crowned Night Heron**
> Stocky and compact heron. Often tucks neck into its body creating a hunchbacked look. Adults have a black cap and back that contrasts with its whitish to pale gray belly and gray wings.
> © Jeff Timmons

Note the fishing line tangled around the adult bird's feet.  Must be a common trait!

Comment: Thanks for the replies. First, it took this photo from about 60cm distance to this bird with a 50mm prime lens. The bird did not move and i tried to speak calmly to it while robbing loser and closer, hence the pretty crisp image that looks almost like taken with a tele lens. Second: in my post there was some text box in which i entered the location - but once posted i did not observe this particular info was not visible. It was shot at a small beach in Rio de Janeiro, Brasil!

Comment: The tip with "Crowned Night Heron" seems to be accurate, the stocky slightly odd physiology is certainly spot on. The coloration of these birds seems to change according to age, that is somewhat confusing. I thought this particular bird looked already erh "old and wise", but judging by the colours it was only somewhere between juvenile and immature??

Comment: @RudMe — I think this is the correct id since this looks like a Black-crowned Night Heron, which is a common heron with a worldwide distribution. I encourage you to acknowledge Dirigibles work by accepting this well written answer. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages for more information on how to use this site effectively. Thanks! 

Comment: Okay, done (i think). Did indeed not know about this as it is not obvious like it would be with some plain text link